# Convergence rate of Laplace principle in Large Deviations

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, large-deviation-theory, laplace-method

Let $H:A \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous   function defined on   a compact subset  $A\subset \mathbf{R}^n$.  Then the [Laplace principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_principle_(large_deviations_theory)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Laplace%27s%20principle%20is,A%20as%20%CE%B8%20becomes%20large.) shows that
$$
\lim_{\theta\to \infty }\frac{1}{\theta}\log \int_A e^{-\theta H(x)}dx =-\min_{x\in A} H(x).
$$

I was wondering with additional regularity assumptions on $H$, can we establish a convergence rate   in $\theta$?
Has such a problem been studied in the literature?

Comment: Yes.  Google "Watson's lemma" to find out more.

Comment: @kimchilover could you elaborate it further as an answer? Do you mean the lemma in this [webpage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma)?

Comment: Yes. Change variables so that page's $t$ is your $H(x)$ and that page's $x$ is your $\theta$.